# Best tutorial for learning nav_stack

Tags: rviz, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am learning about and experimenting with the Navigation stack. We have a Robotis Turtlebot3 and soon will have a ClearPath Turtlebot2. But the class has 9 students.

I've been scouring google for a nav stack tutorial with actual code that allows me to see the various mov_base capabilities in simulation. I am running Kinetic.

Can someone refer me to a good tutorial that will work on Kinetic and that allows me to understand path planning and work with it. Believe me I searched and have tried to follow many of them (not just from ROS.org) and each one fails in a different way.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/281007/best-tutorial-for-learning-nav_stack/) by [pitosalas](https://answers.ros.org/users/30692/pitosalas/) on ROS Answers with karma: 628 on 2018-01-26

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hey all tutorial work well for all versions but only need some modification and here are the link for turtlebot learning tutorials :

- http://wiki.ros.org/turtlebot_navigation/Tutorials
- http://learn.turtlebot.com/
- http://emanual.robotis.com/docs/en/platform/turtlebot3/overview/

check these link they will help you i am sure about this

---

Originally posted by [lagankapoor](https://answers.ros.org/users/33282/lagankapoor/) with karma: 216 on 2018-01-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1